# Sites for collecting and mapping vocab differences within languages

Tags: resource-request, dialects, vocabulary, online-resources

What are the publicly available websites for mapping (and collecting data) on vocabulary differences within a language?

For French there is

- [Français de nos régions](https://francaisdenosregions.com/participez-a-lenquete/).

For English there is

- [Tweetolectology (for the UK)](https://tweetolectology.com/), and
- [Harvard Dialect Center(for the US)](http://dialect.redlog.net/)

Are there similar ones for German, Spanish, Italian, Russian, Mandarin, Hindi, etc? Are there better ones for French and English?

Comment: Do you think it would be better to ask this separately at each language specific site?

Comment: There's also the [George Mason University Speech Accent Archive](https://accent.gmu.edu/), with hundreds of people pronouncing the same paragraph. Each person's production is available, along with an IPA transcription and data on age, birthplace, native language(s), etc. Strictly English pronunciation, but covers all native dialect areas and many foreign accents.

Answer (score 1):

For German there are

- https://atlas-alltagssprache.de for differences in the usage of contemporary German, aiming at regional colloquial German, not at the basic dialects
- https://www.uni-marburg.de/de/fb09/dsa/projekte/digitaler-wenkeratlas-diwa Maps German dialects at the beginning of the 20th century
- https://www.regionalsprache.de/ with links to other German dialect resources